# Getting list of contacts from phone book in Iphone application

Tags: iphone

I just want the all contacts list in my application, in NSArray or NSDictionary object or in any other form. My intense is that my application do also have its own contacts. Now I want to show my application's contact and native contacts in my application's phone book. So I just want the list of native contacts in some way so that I can show it along with my application's contact list. Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has a programming guide for the address book framework that should give all the information you need:

[Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744)